# Ubuntu 20.04 not working on one of my machines, how to follow up on error report?

Tags: system-installation, 20.04

I have a machine (a mobile workstation built in 2012) which simply doesn't work with Ubuntu 20.04 anymore. I verified the installation media and the desktop ISO doesn't even boot and the server ISO boots, but as I am prompted to enter my name, user name and password, I get/got an error dialog.

I retried *once*, obviously. To see whether it was a glitch or I had simply hit the wrong button. The error was the same. What I could glean from the error report was some stack backtrace of some Python script (seemingly it was related to my partitioning settings ... sda1 reformatted to ext4 for `/`, sda5 untouched and unmounted). I decided to submit to Canonical as I am a software developer myself and know how hard it is to fix software without meaningful error reports. The sheer amount of data was somewhat worrying though and in `less` (presumably) it was hard to sift through the data. But I decided to drop into the shell on another `tty` and sent it off anyway.

Now my question is, is there a way to follow up on this somehow? Or is that it, submit error report, be done with it?

I have a Launchpad account, **so is there a way to "claim" my error report there, or is Launchpad not used for this?**

---

I meanwhile managed to get the installation to work, which subsequently left my system in an unbootable state. What I figured out was that before I had an classic DOS-based partition table and so even though I told the installer to merely reformat the `sda1` partition, it failed. When I told it to use the whole disk, it worked and ended up creating a GPT-based partition table. The result was that my system would no longer boot (the BIOS was set to legacy mode).

So since I am not a rookie, I figured out that - having created a GPT - the system was probably going to be bootable by switching to UEFI with CSM or UEFI native. So I tried those two. Neither worked.

I then tried to update the BIOS. Previously I was running with a BIOS from 2018, but there was another from 2019 available. This was quite the nightmare, because the vendor (HP) basically only provides tools for Windows. Alas, I managed by creating a "recovery flash drive" in the end.

The new BIOS version did not change anything in regard to the attempted installation, though.

However, I then retried the installation with UEFI native mode and so got it to install.

After successful installation I went ahead and used `tasksel` to get myself a minimal desktop installation from where I can now work.

There are some details above which could be interesting for the developers, but I still have no way of following up on the sent error report.